# Setting Android ListActivity starting position

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm displaying data coming from SQLite in a ListActivity. The user can click on an list element which sends him to an Activity that updates the DB.

Once the update Activity is finished, the user gets sent back to the original ListActivity.

When the user comes back from the ListActivity I would like the ListView to be positioned to display the data that she just updated (e.g. in the first position of possible).

I tried positioning the Cursor to point to the entry I want displayed; but that doesn't seem to work (see code below for code example).

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mDbCursor = mDbAdapter.getCursor();
    long id = getIntent().getLongExtra(FIRST_ID, -1); // Id of updated row.
    while (mDbCursor.moveToNext() && getId(mDbCursor) != id) {
    }
    .
    . calling setListAdapter(SimpleCursorAdapter);
    .
}
```

I do think the cursor is positioned to the correct row after exiting the while loop.

Comment: Both answers below recommending `getListView().setSelection(int position)` got me on the right track. I actually ended up passing the current position from the ListActivity to the update Activity. The update Activity then passes the current position back to the ListActivity. This saves looping over the Cursor and will work because no adds or deletes are made to the DB table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `getListView().setSelection(int position)` on your ListActivity? The `position` argument starts at 0 for the list, so it's not the same thing as your `id` variable, but in your while loop you could count from zero as you iterate through the Cursor and use that as the position.

Comment: Thanks @joel. Somehow I missed that part of the API!

Answer (score 2):

The cursor initial position is not considered. You have to use listView.setSelection(int position), and get the position according to your id:

```
for (int position = 0; mDbCursor.moveToNext() && getId(mDbCursor) != id; position++) {}
setListAdapter(SimpleCursorAdapter);
getListView.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: Thanks @njzk2. Somehow I missed that part of the API!